# sdkman is missing a specific java version

Tags: java, sdkman

I have SDKMAN 5.7.3+337 on an Ubuntu 18.10 which is listing these available versions for java:

```
     13.ea.17-open   > * 10.0.2-open         1.0.0-rc-12-grl
     12.0.1-zulu       * 9.0.7-zulu          1.0.0-rc-11-grl
     12.0.1-librca       9.0.4-open          1.0.0-rc-10-grl
     12.0.1-sapmchn      8.0.212-zulu        1.0.0-rc-9-grl
     12.0.1-open         8.0.212-amzn        1.0.0-rc-8-grl
   + 12.0.0-open         8.0.212-librca
     11.0.3-sapmchn    + 8.0.202-zulu
     11.0.3-zulu         8.0.202.j9-adpt
     11.0.3-amzn         8.0.202.hs-adpt
     11.0.3-librca       8.0.202-zulufx
   + 11.0.2-open         7.0.222-zulu
     11.0.2.j9-adpt      6.0.119-zulu
     11.0.2.hs-adpt      1.0.0-rc-15-grl
     11.0.2-zulufx       1.0.0-rc-14-grl
     10.0.2-zulu         1.0.0-rc-13-grl
```

while the same SDKMAN version on an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (as WSL in Windows 10) shows:

```
13.ea.17-open     * 9.0.4-open          1.0.0-rc-11-grl
12.0.1-sapmchn      8.0.212-zulu        1.0.0-rc-10-grl
12.0.1-zulu         8.0.212-amzn        1.0.0-rc-9-grl 
12.0.1-open         8.0.212-librca      1.0.0-rc-8-grl 
12.0.1-librca     + 8.0.202-zulu 
11.0.3-sapmchn      8.0.202.j9-adpt
11.0.3-zulu         8.0.202.hs-adpt
11.0.3-amzn         8.0.202-zulufx
11.0.3-librca     + 8.0.191-oracle
11.0.2.j9-adpt      7.0.222-zulu
11.0.2.hs-adpt      6.0.119-zulu
11.0.2-zulufx       1.0.0-rc-15-grl
10.0.2-zulu         1.0.0-rc-14-grl
10.0.2-open         1.0.0-rc-13-grl
9.0.7-zulu          1.0.0-rc-12-grl
```

where `11.0.2-open` is missing. Why this happens and how should I solve this?

PS: I already run `sdk selfupdate` and `sdk update`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that downloading the missing version:

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

then unpacking to:

```
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/
```

then renaming the extracted directory:

```
mv ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/jdk-11.0.2 ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open
```

solves the problem.

PS: of course, you'll have to change `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/` to match your SDKMAN installation path (if not the default one)

Comment: For not having the path issue when using a downloaded version, it would be better to use the sdk to install the local version as shown here (https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion)

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but I downloaded the MacOS openJdk package for Java 15, which matches the expected dir for Mac packages (ie., Contents/Home Contents/MacOS ).  So I had to move things around so that the candidates/15.0.2-open dir contained the standard JAVA_HOME layout ( bin/ lib/ etc...)

Comment: "so that the candidates/15.0.2-open dir contained the standard JAVA_HOME layout ( bin/ lib/ etc...)" - I'm pretty sure that's the way it's supposed to be, but is just a hunch.

Comment: For me, afterwards the status of the java version was `local_only`, and I had to `$ sdk use java X.Y.Z` for it to be installed.

Comment: FYI I had to manually create symlinks to:

```$ ls -l ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.1-open/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  ... 19.0.1.jdk
lrwxr-xr-x  ... bin -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... conf -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/conf/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... include -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... jmods -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... legal -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/legal/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... lib -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/
lrwxr-xr-x  ... release -> 19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/release```

Answer (score 16):

Even if it is not listed, you can still install the version you require.  At least, it worked for me with `java 10.0.2-open`, which, in my case, did not show up.  Give it a try and run the command `sdk install java 11.0.2-open`

Another way.

You can install any version of java locally (use any way you want to do the local installation), and then register this installation using this command:

```
sdk install java 17-zulu /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Take a look at [SDK man Local Instalation](https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion)

Comment: Does anybody know why that is? I was surprised I didn't see java 14 listed there, but I am able to install thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: Can you give me the command that you tried for installing java 14, I can not able to download that version @T.S

Comment: @sagarr I used: sdk install java 14.0.2.hs-adpt

Comment: one more thing @T.S. when I search `sdk list java` I did not find version 14 there, how could you found it?

Comment: @sagarrI checked the available version number from here https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html and then I just constructed the sdkman version naming myself {java version}.{hs - hotspot}-{distribution adopt, etc.}

Comment: But I get this `mv: target '/home/darw/.sdkman/candidates/java/15.0.2-open' is not a directory`

Comment: FYI, this is because SDKMAN! keeps the outdated versions in their DB, but has them set as [invisible](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-db-migrations/issues/170#issuecomment-750008113).

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to install a version not listed by e.g. `sdk list java` is to just write `sdk install java 11` then press the `TAB` key. This will initiate autocomplete which will give you an autocomplete list to choose from.

Disclaimer: this works for me on macos in a terminal running zsh.

Comment: I have the same setup, mac with m1 and zsh. I needed ver11 from java.net but it wasn't listed, only versions 20 and 19. As a last resort I installed 19 but after I did that and I did `sdk list java` I saw that now it was listing also version 11?? Weird behaviour, but now I just installed 11 and it worked.

Comment: @Dusko Thanks for the info. If you can reproduce it, you may consider opening an issue on sdkman's github repo: https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli