# How do I list all versions of Java available for install in sdkman?

Tags: java, sdkman

On a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 box with sdkman I only get a subset of the java versions available on my other (old) Ubuntu 18.04 box. Both are running SDKMAN 5.7.3+337. What am I missing?

I checked the sdkman docs, but could not find som obvious config option I have missed. Also I found this post, which seems similar to mine - though the solution seems rather complex (and not in the spirit of sdkman): [sdkman is missing a specific java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809928/sdkman-is-missing-a-specific-java-version)

Running sdkman I get the following differences in output:

````
New box:
$ sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 BellSoft      |     | 12.0.2       | librca  |            | 12.0.2-librca       
               |     | 11.0.4       | librca  |            | 11.0.4-librca       
               |     | 8.0.222      | librca  |            | 8.0.222-librca      
================================================================================
Use the Identifier for installation:

    $ sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
================================================================================```



Old box:

$ sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AdoptOpenJDK  |     | 12.0.1.j9    | adpt    |            | 12.0.1.j9-adpt      
               |     | 12.0.1.hs    | adpt    |            | 12.0.1.hs-adpt      
               |     | 11.0.4.j9    | adpt    |            | 11.0.4.j9-adpt      
               |     | 11.0.4.hs    | adpt    |            | 11.0.4.hs-adpt      
               |     | 8.0.222.j9   | adpt    |            | 8.0.222.j9-adpt     
               |     | 8.0.222.hs   | adpt    |            | 8.0.222.hs-adpt     
 Amazon        |     | 11.0.4       | amzn    |            | 11.0.4-amzn         
               |     | 8.0.222      | amzn    |            | 8.0.222-amzn        
 Azul Zulu     |     | 12.0.2       | zulu    |            | 12.0.2-zulu         
               |     | 11.0.4       | zulu    |            | 11.0.4-zulu         
               |     | 11.0.1       | zulu    | local only | 11.0.1-zulu         
               |     | 10.0.2       | zulu    |            | 10.0.2-zulu         
               |     | 9.0.7        | zulu    |            | 9.0.7-zulu          
               |     | 8.0.222      | zulu    |            | 8.0.222-zulu        
               |     | 8.0.181      | zulu    | local only | 8.0.181-zulu        
               |     | 7.0.232      | zulu    |            | 7.0.232-zulu        
               | >>> | 7.0.191      | zulu    | local only | 7.0.191-zulu        
               |     | 6.0.119      | zulu    |            | 6.0.119-zulu        
 Azul ZuluFX   |     | 11.0.2       | zulufx  |            | 11.0.2-zulufx       
               |     | 8.0.202      | zulufx  |            | 8.0.202-zulufx      
 BellSoft      |     | 12.0.2       | librca  |            | 12.0.2-librca       
               |     | 11.0.4       | librca  |            | 11.0.4-librca       
               |     | 8.0.222      | librca  |            | 8.0.222-librca      
 GraalVM       |     | 19.2.0       | grl     |            | 19.2.0-grl          
               |     | 19.2.0.1     | grl     |            | 19.2.0.1-grl        
               |     | 19.1.1       | grl     |            | 19.1.1-grl          
               |     | 19.0.2       | grl     |            | 19.0.2-grl          
               |     | 1.0.0        | grl     |            | 1.0.0-rc-16-grl     
 Java.net      |     | 14.ea.14     | open    |            | 14.ea.14-open       
               |     | 13.ea.33     | open    |            | 13.ea.33-open       
               |     | 12.0.2       | open    |            | 12.0.2-open         
               |     | 11.0.2       | open    |            | 11.0.2-open         
               |     | 10.0.2       | open    |            | 10.0.2-open         
               |     | 9.0.4        | open    |            | 9.0.4-open          
 SAP           |     | 12.0.2       | sapmchn |            | 12.0.2-sapmchn      
               |     | 11.0.4       | sapmchn |            | 11.0.4-sapmchn      
================================================================================
Use the Identifier for installation:

    $ sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
================================================================================
````

Any ideas?

Comment: I keep running across this question when I look up how to list currently installed versions of Java.  I've updated the title to make it clear this question is not about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now finally realised why I get these different lists. The new box is running a 32 bit version of Ubuntu. Only a small subset of pubished JDK's apparently support 32 bit.

Comment: This also applies to Apple Silicon M1 (arm64). Run command in Rosetta 2 (x86_64)