# Building Xef with Java 19 fails

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm integrating Xef with the latest snapshot of Playframework that supports scala 3.3 and I bumped into an issue, so I went and git cloned Xef.ai repo and I started getting issues by trying to build from source the Xef project.

```
git clone git@github.com:xebia-functional/xef.git
cd xef
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

I'm using sdkman to manage my multiple java versions.

However, I've noticed that `sdk ls java` doesn't have java 19.
So I tried to build Xef with java 20, but It looks like the project needs to be upgraded to Kotlin 1.9 so that target is available. Given that's a bigger lift.
So I downloaded java 19 from https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=19

I had to follow this SO [sdkman is missing a specific java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809928/sdkman-is-missing-a-specific-java-version) to accomplish my goal.

But now I'm facing the following issue, I'm kind of new to Kotlin, my PATH is correctly setup: /Users/raul/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.2-tem/bin, I wonder what else is needed, will keep looking;

```
./gradlew build
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :kotlin-loom
Kotlin DSL property assignment is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :xef-scala
signing.keyId Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY_ID environment variable are missing
signing.key Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY environment variable are missing
signing.passphrase Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY_PASSPHRASE environment variable are missing

> Configure project :xef-scala-cats
signing.keyId Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY_ID environment variable are missing
signing.key Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY environment variable are missing
signing.passphrase Gradle property and SIGNING_KEY_PASSPHRASE environment variable are missing
Path for java installation '/Users/raul/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.2-tem/Contents/Home' (SDKMAN!) does not contain a java executable
Path for java installation '/Users/raul/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.2-tem/Contents/Home' (Current JVM) does not contain a java executable
Path for java installation '/Users/raul/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.2-tem/Contents/Home' (SDKMAN!) does not contain a java executable

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlin-loom:compileKotlin'.
> No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=19, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
> No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlin-loom:compileKotlin'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:68)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:49)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:148)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:122)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.discoverNodeRelationships(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:184)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddEntryNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:156)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:131)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:123)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.java:53)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.java:72)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:228)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:221)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:45)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:282)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:178)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:115)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:101)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:74)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$8(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:178)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:178)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:167)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:73)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:150)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:38)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph.scheduleWork(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:192)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:37)
  at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:36)
  at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:109)
  at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController.scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:63)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.NoToolchainAvailableException: No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=19, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.downloadToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:167)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.query(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:143)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.lambda$resolveToolchain$1(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.resolveToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:107)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.lambda$findMatchingToolchain$0(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:72)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.WithSideEffectProvider.calculateOwnValue(WithSideEffectProvider.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.calculateOwnValue(FlatMapProvider.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:164)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:26)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:245)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:239)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:98)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.lambda$walkNestedProvider$0(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:142)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedChild(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:190)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedProvider(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:141)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedProvider(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:123)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.walkNested(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:60)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.lambda$walkChildren$3(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:85)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedChild(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:196)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedChild(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:177)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker$InstanceTypeMetadataWalker.walkNestedChild(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:123)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.lambda$walkChildren$4(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:85)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.walkChildren(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:83)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.annotations.AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.walk(AbstractTypeMetadataWalker.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.properties.bean.DefaultPropertyWalker.visitProperties(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitAnnotatedProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:45)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.visitDependencies(DefaultTaskInputs.java:195)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultTaskDependency.java:112)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:103)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
  ... 142 more
  Caused by: org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.ToolchainDownloadFailedException: No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.install.DefaultJavaToolchainProvisioningService.tryInstall(DefaultJavaToolchainProvisioningService.java:113)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.downloadToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:164)
  ... 186 more
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
10 actionable tasks: 10 up-to-date
```

Comment: Could you share your build gradle? Or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also not sure if it will be possible to use jdk 19 with play framework. They added [experimental support for jdk 17 in play 2.8](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases/tag/2.8.15) and it will be stable for play 2.9

Comment: I actually git clone the xef repo and tried to build it. The reason I wanted to do that is because,  I was running a project with play(from source) and xef, which worked just fine, but I was getting some issues with the prompts, hence, I wanted to dive deeper into Xef source code, and that’s why I faced this issue, because I wanted to build it from source.

Comment: Instead of follow the suggestion in the question about how to install missing dependency in sdkman, have you tried what sdkman says in its docs about [how to install a local version](https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion). Maybe that could help with the problem of not finding a local install.

Comment: As I said before, without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is hard to guess. please edit your post trying to detail what were the steps yo followed to get there and share how your `build.gradle` looks like

Comment: Thanks a lot @GastónSchabas Installing the local version fixed it. I didn't read the docs for a local installation :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GastónSchabas for helping me in the comments.

So in summary, I cloned the repository

```
git clone git@github.com:xebia-functional/xef.git
cd xef
./gradlew build
```

Pretty much I needed to download the gz file from adoptium and then install it locally using the `sdk` command:

```
sdk install java 19.0.2-tem ~/Downloads/jdk-19.0.2+7/Contents/Home
```

I also needed to install java 11:

```
sdk install java 11.0.19-tem
```

And finally:

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Worked like a charm.